# Objective c Basico, erro no setNome EXEC_BAD_ACESS

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile, xcode

Bom pessoal quando entra no setNome da minha classe acontece o erro EXEC_BAD_ACESS
abaixo vai o código:

**Classe Registro**

```
//
//  Registro.h
//  Agenda
//
//  Created by Renan Vicente de Farias on 01/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Renan Vicente de Farias. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Registro : NSObject

- (id) initWithNomeCelular:(NSString *)novoNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular;
- (id) initWithNomeTelefone:(NSString *)novoNome andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone;
- (id) initWithNomeCelularEmail:(NSString *)novoNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular     andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail; 
- (id) initWithNomeTelefoneEmail:(NSString *)novoNome andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail;
- (id) initWithAll:(NSString *)novoNome andSobreNome:(NSString *)novoSobreNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail;
- (NSString *) nome;
- (void)setNome:(NSString *)novoNome;
- (NSString *) sobreNome;
- (void) setSobreNome : (NSString *) novoSobreNome;
- (NSString *) celular;
- (void) setCelular : (NSString *) novoCelular;
- (NSString *) telefone;
- (void) setTelefone : (NSString *) novoTelefone;
- (NSString *) email;
- (void ) setEmail : (NSString *) novoEmail;
@end
```

**Implementação:**

```
//
//  Registro.m
//  Agenda
//
//  Created by Renan Vicente de Farias on 01/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Renan Vicente de Farias. All rights reserved.
//

#import "Registro.h"

@implementation Registro

{
    NSString *nome;
    NSString *sobreNome;
    NSString *celular;
    NSString *telefone;
    NSString *email;
}

- (id)initWithNomeCelular:(NSString *)novoNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular{

   self = [super init];
   [self setNome:novoNome];
   [self setCelular:novoCelular];
   return self;
}

- (id)initWithNomeTelefone:(NSString *)novoNome andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone{

self = [super init];
[self setNome:novoNome];
[self setCelular:novoTelefone];

return self;
}

- (id)initWithNomeCelularEmail:(NSString *)novoNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail{
self = [super init];
[self setNome:novoNome];
[self setCelular:novoCelular];
[self setEmail:novoEmail];

return self;
}
- (id)initWithNomeTelefoneEmail:(NSString *)novoNome andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail{
self = [super init];

[self setNome:novoNome];
[self setTelefone:novoTelefone];
[self setEmail:novoEmail];

return self;
}

- (id)initWithAll:(NSString *)novoNome andSobreNome:(NSString *)novoSobreNome andCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular andTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone andEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail{

self = [super init];
[self setNome:novoNome];
[self setSobreNome:novoSobreNome];
[self setCelular:novoCelular];
[self setTelefone:novoTelefone];
[self setEmail:novoEmail];

return self;
}

- (NSString *) nome{
    return nome;
}

- (void)setNome:(NSString *)novoNome{
    self.nome = novoNome;
}

- (NSString *)sobreNome{
    return sobreNome;
}

- (void)setSobreNome:(NSString *)novoSobreNome{
    self.sobreNome = novoSobreNome;
}

- (NSString *)celular{
    return celular;
}

- (void) setCelular:(NSString *)novoCelular{
    self.celular = novoCelular;
}

- (NSString *)telefone{
    return telefone;
}

- (void)setTelefone:(NSString *)novoTelefone{
    self.telefone = novoTelefone;
}

- (NSString *)email{
    return email;
}

- (void)setEmail:(NSString *)novoEmail{
    self.email = novoEmail;
}

@end
```

Por favor me ajudem,
desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renan, a forma correta de criar a interface de acesso aos atributos da classe é através de propriedades. Para cada par de getter/setter, crie uma propriedade. Exemplo:

```
@property(copy, nonatomic) NSString *nome;
```

Isso vai gerar os métodos de acesso automaticamente. Você não precisa implementá-los no .m e nem declarar `(NSString *) nome; e (void)setNome:(NSString *)novoNome;` no .h.

A declaração da propriedade vai criar uma variável de instância (i-var) chamada `_nome`. Dentro da classe você pode ler/escrever no atributo usando a interface da propriedade, ex: `self.nome = @"Renam"` ou acessando o i-var direto, ex: `_nome = @"Renam"`. A diferença é que usando self.nome o método setNome será implicitamente chamado e na outra abordagem não. O mesmo vale para o getter.

Comment: Muito obrigado!